# How can I apply http_referer constraint in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to apply constraint in routes.rb on routes using http_referer how can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it one of two ways as far as I know.

Easier, but with less control:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :waffles, :constraints => {:referer => 'http://wafflesarerad.com'}
```

More control:

```
#config/routes.rb
require 'referer_constraint'
constraints (RefererConstraint) do
  resources :waffles
end

#lib/referer_constraint.rb
class RefererConstraint
  def self.matches?(request)
    request.referer = 'http://wafflesarerad.com' ? true :false
  end
end
```

You can contstrain by any part of the request with the `:constraints =>` hash in routes.rb.  You can also right custom constraint classes that implement a class level method of `matches?(request)`.  That method should return true/false as to whether or not the constraint is met.

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem. How can I know what are the possible values for constraint hash?

Answer (score 0):

To improve upon Patrick's answer, I would suggest

- Placing the constraint class in app/constraints/ instead of lib/, Rails will then pick it up automatically and you won't need to stick a require statement at the top of your routes file
- Not using the ternary (?:) operator unnecessarily

I would do this instead:

```
#config/routes.rb
constraints (RefererConstraint) do
  resources :waffles
end

#app/constraints/referer_constraint.rb
class RefererConstraint
  def self.matches?(request)
    request.referer == 'http://wafflesarerad.com'
  end
end
```